# jquery max date on datepicker date format mm/dd/yyy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to webpages.  I have been trying to restrict the max date selection on the date picker to 1 year out.  Each year the date would extend out to the next year.  Example current year 2018 the max date on the datepicker would be 6/30/2019.  Next year the max date would change to 6/30/2020, etc.  Below is the code I am using before making changes to get the max date on the date picker:

```
 $j('#dbLASTDAY').datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy" }).val('~(last_day)');

<div>
  <label for="dbLASTDAY">Last Day(mm/dd/yyyy)</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="06/30/2018" name="lastDate" value="" id="dbLASTDAY" size="11" maxsize="11">
</div>
```

I have tried multiple ways to set the max date.  The input type must stay as text and the date format must stay as mm/dd/yyyy.  Any help is greatly appreciated as I am so new to this.

Comment: Have you tried the official documentation, I remember the syntax was ` `datepicker({dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",endDate:'6/30/2020'})`.

Comment: I did try the above $j('#dbLASTDAY').datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", endDate: '6/30/2025' }).val('~(last_day)');          The date picker calendar extends out past the 6/30/2025 end date and I can type a date in greater than 6/30/2025 as well.

Comment: why you put this at the end: `.val('~(last_day)');`?

Comment: better to let the user chooses the date from the calendar box, and make the input readonly from the html

Comment: I'm not sure why we use .val('~(last_day)');   I was told the software package requires it and we have to add it.  The user can currently select the date the problem is that I want to restrict the max date they can select but I want it to be dynamic and each time the year changes I want the max date to go out 365 days from the current year.

Comment: It seems no matter what code I put in the calendar will allow the user to select any date they want (ex 6/30/4999)

Comment: I once used [this datepicker](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker), and I had proceeded that way `$("input").datepicker({format: "mm/dd/yy",endDate:'6/30/2020',autoHide:true})`. as you can see some syntaxes are differents.

Comment: I have gotten the date picker to restrict the calendar dates by doing: $j('#dbLASTDAY').datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", maxDate:'+12m +10d', 
  minDate: -365}).val('~(last_day)');       However the user can still enter a date of 6/15/2055.  Any ideas on how to restrict the dates in the following without changing input type=text to input type=date? :    <div>
            <label for="dbLASTDAY">LastDay (mm/dd/yyyy)</label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="06/30/2018" name="LastDay" value="" id="dbLASTDAY"  size="11" maxsize="11">
        </div>

Comment: it's not safe to prevent it in the front end, make sure that you receive the date needed in the backend. or if there is a pop up where the user can choose a date from it, basically put the input read-only, `<input type="text" readonly='readonly' placeholder="06/30/2018" name="lastDate" value="" id="dbLASTDAY" size="11" maxsize="11">` and let the user chooses the date only from the date picker box

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  Problem resolved.